# Cloudinary AI background removal fatal error

Tags: php, cloudinary

I am trying to use Cloudinary AI background removal tool. This is the code I am using (Code snippet provided by Cloudinary)

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slike-prirode-za-desktop-757.jpg",
array(
    "public_id" => "dog_couch",
    "background_removal" => "cloudinary_ai"
    ));

}
```

I get this error 
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cloudinary\Error' not found in /storage/ssd5/884/7393884/public_html/Uploader.php:534 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/884/7393884/public_html/Uploader.php(408): Cloudinary\Uploader::call_api('upload', Array, Array, 'https://www.pop...') #1 /storage/ssd5/884/7393884/public_html/Uploader.php(101): Cloudinary\Uploader::call_cacheable_api('upload', Array, Array, 'https://www.pop...') #2 /storage/ssd5/884/7393884/public_html/index.php(13): Cloudinary\Uploader::upload('https://www.pop...', Array) #3 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/884/7393884/public_html/Uploader.php on line 534**

When I use part just for uploading it works perfectly

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("https://www.popwebdesign.net/popart_blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slike-prirode-za-desktop-757.jpg");
}
```

as soon as I add array part I get the error. I can't see what I am doing wrong since this code is directly from cloudinary. I've found it here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_ai_background_removal_addon

I have tried to search the internet, but could not find a solution for this. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please check that you are subscribed to that AI Background Removal addon from within your account.

Comment: @AleksandarKostadinov Actually that was it, the code was good all the way. Thank you very much!